# How do you display a section of plain text in GitHub markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

I'm having a hard time finding any real answer to this (really simple?) question on Google, and I'm starting to worry that there is no solution.

I am learning GitHub markdown. I would like to show some example code that contains fake email address like `user@example.com`. But GitHub insists on auto-linking this text. I also have a large chunk of text that has many special characters.

Is there a way to escape blocks or sections so that no special characters are processed, and no auto-links are generated?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can wrap such text in pre tags.

```
<pre>Text I want left alone@donotlinkme.example</pre>
```

I just tested this out on github.

Comment: I tried this but it actually messed with some of the formatting on github. The ```text answer is safer.

Answer (score 97):

Wrap the block in backticks:

````
```text
code();
address@domain.example
```
````

Comment: That sometimes triggers syntax highlighting though. You can (probably, I haven't checked) fix that by adding the word "text" right after the opening three backticks at the start of the code fence:

    ```text

Comment: This works in github formatted comments, such as issue reports. Also interesting to note that this works in Discord. You can specify syntax highlighting by including a language name on the same line as the first triple back ticks. For example, ```js will block the encapsulated text and highlight Javascript syntax.

Comment: @danday74 at the time, the accepted answer was the only answer available. I do not want to take the green check mark away from a correct answer that came first, however I gave an upvote to this. Hopefully, users will have the habit of seeking more than just the first answer on the page.

Comment: for single line text you can also use single backticks like \`address@domain.com\`

Answer (score 8):

This is all part of the [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html) syntax. The last link shows every GitHub markdown trick.

So this will work also:

```
~~~text
code();
address@domain.example
~~~
```

Comment: This is actually what helps the most if you want to show how to use markdown itself. Unlike the backticks or XML/HTML like `<pre>` . . . `</pre>` this seems to allow truly verbatim text.