# How to serve raw Markdown in Jekyll/GHpages?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I would like my GitHub pages website (long story) to serve a few unrendered Markdown pages.

If I leave the `.md` file, even without metadata, in the root level of the repository, it gets converted to html. I want it to stay Markdown.

If I add the `.md` file to `exclude` in `_config.yml`, then it doesn't show up at all in GHpages.

I can get this to work in vanilla Jekyll using `keep_files`, but I suspect it's not possible to get GHpages to see those files, as they're inside `_site`, which gets ignored by Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [display plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525877/how-do-you-display-a-section-of-plain-text-in-github-markdown) in Markdown, so one option is to wrap the contents of your `.md` file inside `<pre>` tags:

```
<pre>
# Your header

Your paragraph, etc.
</pre>
```

Or, if you don't want to modify your Markdown files:

1. Place your `.md` file inside `_includes` directory, e.g. `_includes/raw.md`
2. Create a page anywhere (and doesn't matter if extension is `.md` or `.html`), and use `include`, inside `<pre>` tags:

```html
---
---
<pre>{% include raw.md %}</pre>
```

(The path after `include` is relative to `_includes` directory.)

This will also display your Markdown file unrendered.

Comment: The `<pre>` tags were causing trouble because I set the `permalink:` to `blah.md`, so I removed them and your second version works brilliantly.