# Github pages strips YAML header from Rmd file

Tags: yaml, r-markdown, github-pages

I would like to be able to have students download Rmd files from my website. However, when I use Github pages to serve Rmd files, the YAML header is being stripped away.

Here is the raw file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdfoote/Communication-and-Social-Networks/spring-2022/week_3/r_markdown_example.Rmd

And here it is on Github pages:
https://jeremydfoote.com/Communication-and-Social-Networks/week_3/r_markdown_example.Rmd

The YAML header is removed, but everything else is the same. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: I think, it is a same bug with this: https://github.com/ClaudioZandonella/trackdown/issues/17

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve raw Markdown in Jekyll/GHpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828739/how-to-serve-raw-markdown-in-jekyll-ghpages)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, I don't think so. I want students to be able to download the Rmd files and open them in RStudio, not display them as plaintext.

Comment: Well, you have to make it plain text, otherwise the Jekyll processor behind GitHub pages will eat up your header

Comment: Related: https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/prevent-jekyll-from-processing-markdown-files-which-are-supposed-to-be-downloaded/1178/4

Answer (score 1):

If you include .nojekyll as a file in the root of your pages repository, this .Rmd files that are downloaded from your pages will not be stripped of their YAML.

See discussion here: https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/